# JAVAFX Filling several TableView with Map<String, String> by key

Tags: java, javafx

I have 4-5 `TableView`s and one `Map<String,String>` (creating from PDF Form). I need  to populate the `TableView` using a key from the `Map` (first `String`) and the value for this key (second `String`).

Definition from FXML (for one table):

```
@FXML
private TableView<Map.Entry<String, String>> INFO_TABLEVIEW;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>,String> COLUMN_INFO_NAME = new TableColumn<>("NAME");
@FXML
private TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>,String> COLUMN_INFO_VALUE = new TableColumn<>("VALUE");
```

This is loop to search the `Map` by key

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry:Param.entrySet()){
    switch (entry.getKey().substring(0,3)){
    case "INF":{
        if (entry.getKey().substring(5,8).contentEquals("BEG")){
            try{
                System.out.println("BEG"); //ok

                COLUMN_INFO_WST_NAME.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, String>, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> p) {
                            System.out.println("AAAA"); //not enter this loop
                            return new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getKey());
                        }
                    });
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
ObservableList<Map.Entry<String,String>> listData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Zapytanie_Parametry.entrySet());
INFO_TABLEVIEW = new TableView<>(listData);

INFO_TABLEVIEW.getColumns().setAll(COLUMN_INFO_NAME,COLUMN_INFO_VALUE);
```

I am wondering if someone could help me to understand properly how to do this.

Comment: I can do it by div the key and value to seperate list and then use Table.setItems(list). But maybe there is another way to do this from one map with switch by key without using additional list?